# How to make select with extra columns that depends on existing ones

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There goes example:

```
select * from table
```

and got

```
ID | NAME | MAIL             | BOSS_ID |
1  | Mike | mike@mike.com    | 2       |
2  | Josh | josh@hotmail.com | null    |
```

What I actually want to do is make SELECT statement (somehow?) to show two more columns like:

```
ID | NAME | MAIL             | BOSS_ID | BOSS_NAME | BOSS_MAIL
1  | Mike | mike@dfsfs.com   | 2       | Josh      | josh@dsa.com
2  | Josh | josh@dfsa.com    | null    | null      | null
```

I know it looks silly, but that what I exactly have been asked to do...
All hints are much appreciatted!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Do you have another table with the Boss information in it? i.e. BOSS_ID, BOSS_NAME, BOSS_MAIL

If so the above comment should get you were you want as that would be joined on BOSS_ID

Answer (score 3):

You do an outer join to the table itself on `ID` and `BOSS_ID`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91d9b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(10),
  Mail varchar(20),
  BOSS_ID int
)
insert into YourTable values
(1  , 'Mike' , 'mike@mike.com'    , 2),
(2  , 'Josh' , 'josh@hotmail.com' , null)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T1.ID, 
       T1.Name,
       T1.Mail,
       T2.Name as BossName,
       T2.Mail as BossMail
from YourTable as T1
  left outer join YourTable as T2
    on T1.BOSS_ID = T2.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91d9b/1/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME |             MAIL | BOSSNAME |         BOSSMAIL |
|----|------|------------------|----------|------------------|
|  1 | Mike |    mike@mike.com |     Josh | josh@hotmail.com |
|  2 | Josh | josh@hotmail.com |   (null) |           (null) |
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, I didn't think about ID and BOSS_ID being the same identifier.

Comment: Good idea, but still I have to use temp table... because if I would try:

select * from 
(some select statement) AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
T1 AS T2
ON T1.BOSS_ID = T2.ID

it would not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot SELECT columns that do not exist. You will need to add them. You would want an ALTER TABLE statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD BOSS_NAME VARCHAR( 255 )
```